# objective-c loading data from excel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm writing an application for the iPad that will tell us whether or not someone is on court at a tennis tournament. Basically, just an application with a list of names each with an on/off button next to them. Once the on button is pressed, their name turns red, thus they are on court.

Is there any way, to make this easier for myself, I would be able to connect it to my computer and load in a list of names once the application is complete? That would save me from having to individually enter/modify names manually.

Thanks in advance,
Louis.

Comment: you could export your excel table to a csv file and import that file into your app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though your question is pretty... vague, one suggestion :

importing Spreadsheet-like data could easily be done by import the `.csv` version (Comma-separated value) of a Spreadsheet.

> A **comma-separated values (CSV)** file stores tabular data (numbers and
>   text) in plain-text form. Plain text means that the file is a sequence
>   of characters, with no data that has to be interpreted instead, as
>   binary numbers. A CSV file consists of any number of records,
>   separated by line breaks of some kind; each record consists of fields,
>   separated by some other character or string, most commonly a literal
>   TAB or comma. Usually, all records have an identical sequence of
>   fields.

**Example :**

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

---

Then, you could simply :

**(1)** Load your csv file as a simple text file

```
NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filename
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                  error:nil];
```

**(2)** Get the lines

```
NSArray* lines = [contents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

**(3)** Parse each line's fields

```
for (NSString* line in lines)
{
    NSArray* fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that'll help. Why is my question vague? I'll try to clarify based on your reply to this.

Comment: @loucidity Well, at a first read, I wasn't actually sure whether you wanted to know how to write the iPad application, if you had trouble loading the data (via web request?), or if you simply wanted to know the best way to import spreadsheet data...

Comment: Just the best way to import spreadsheet data, which you answered pretty well. Thanks again.

Comment: @loucidity You're welcome. :-) To make it easier for the community to understand which answer was really helpful, you may mark the answer as an "Answer"...

Comment: If I dare point it out — splitting on commas will cause any labels with commas inside to be split inappropriately. I guess it'll be things like 'Ed Begley, Jr' that are the only potential issues, so whether that's a real problem or not I don't know.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon- could you guide me for a code that stores array data into xls (microsoft excel) file.?

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSV problem overall, not specific to this code. Indeed if CSV fields contains commas, this is broken. Happens a lot if your numbers standards uses commas for floating point numbers instead of dots.

I tend to always used CSVs where the field separator is TAB (aka "\t") instead of comma. Much more unlikely to be broken. This is usually configurable in CSV-producing tools such as Excel.