# Can I write an excel add-in using Xcode?

Tags: c#, c, xcode, excel

I've written several very helpful excel add-ins using VBA.  I'm using Excel for Mac 2011 Version 14.2.2 (120421).  I'd like to sell the add-ins via a web site.  Can I write the add-ins in Xcode or do I have to use C#?

Comment: Why don't you re-write them in another language like Java or Objective C? You can get libraries for those languages that can access excel documents just like you would from VBA (assuming that's what you're using currently). I think this would be better for selling them.

Comment: That's very helpful.  So, I can write them in in Objective C?  That's great news.  Can you tell me where I can get the libraries for excel in objective C?

Comment: @Hassan is only correct as far as accessing the cells -you wont be able to have any Ribbon Buttons or Context menu's. @Aaron is correct: `You cannot write Excel Add-Ins for Office Mac edition's.`

Comment: i'm very confused. I've written VBA code create toolbars and saved the code as a .xlam (excel add in) file and they work great on my machine.  Am I asking the wrong question. I want to packages these add-ins to sell them.  What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Everyone writes Excel Add-Ins using C# VSTO or with VBA as xlam files. To clarify your asking if you can write add-ins in xcode or [ObjectiveC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287194/where-can-i-find-a-library-to-write-excel-add-ins-in-objective-c) and the answer is no. This Q is turning into a chameleon question. Better to ask a new question about packaging.

Comment: Sure you can. As @JeremyThompson said, you can't do this to actually control Excel itself, but you can read excel documents [easily with Java](http://poi.apache.org/). I guess I spoke too soon with Objective-C, but you can still get [some limited functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9974542/377628) if you make the user export to CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft Support](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/sharepoint2010general/thread/4cf97374-47f4-4ba8-9446-1c91a205f8f9):

> In Office 2011 for Mac, there is no concept of add-ins. So using Excel Add-In is not possible...

You'll need to use VBA or AppleScript to emulate the same behavior.

Comment: Here is documentation of the supported VBA commands in Office 2011: http://mac2.microsoft.com/vb/1033/default.aspx

Comment: I don't mean to be contrary, but i have definitely written add-ins using VBA and sent them to other people to use in excel.  Maybe i'm not saying it correctly, but the other answer to my question seems to have answered me.