# Parsing excel file in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I am developing an iphone app in that I need to parse .xls file. I gone through DhlibLxs parsing but I din't find any solution. Is there any other library or framework that can parse xls file. I am able to parse csv but how to parse excel file.

Comment: I dont know about .xls file. But You can read .csv file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508181/ios-read-in-xls had you try this ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3594651/1298263

Answer (score 4):

**No there is not such which give you 100% accuracy.**

There are few projects which can read xls file but specific to that version of file.

However you can go for CSV file.

---

I with my team did a research for few months and were able to read, but writing was more tougher.

Reason:

Try renaming xlsx file to zip. Then unzip it, you will find some 12 (exact count I missed) files.

Read the contents of each file. Then you will know how all files are interrelated, as one file contains A,B,C... and other contains 1,2,3... third contains the linkage between them, fourth contain the formula, and so on.

On top of this, the file extensions xls, xlsx and 2003, 2007, 2011 keeps on changing.I think only Microsoft excel developers will be knowing about these in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your xls file into .csv file and then read csv file's each line by `NSString`'s method `componentsSeparatedByString:@","`

Answer (score 0):

How about [libxls](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxls/) ?...

It's Description says , it is a "**Library for parsing Excel (XLS) files, with a sample program for converting Excel files into CSV**".

There are some interesting Links Provided in this Question also : [Read data from Excel file in Objective-C (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516129/read-data-from-excel-file-in-objective-c-iphone). You can merge it with the Answer : [objective-c loading data from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974501/objective-c-loading-data-from-excel)

Hope it will be helpful ...!!!

Comment: DHlibxls is an ObjectiveC framework wrapping libxls. Why the person posting the original question couldn't use either is a totally mystery, as both are stable and have seen high usage.